# Set PowerPoint Theme as default using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I can't find the syntax anywhere for setting a PowerPoint theme as the default theme using Excel VBA or PowerPoint (2010) VBA.

To clarify what I'm trying to do, the steps to do this mannually are: go to the design tab in PowerPoint, right click on the desired theme and select the "Set as Default" option. This process sets the default theme and slide master default.

The syntax below will set the theme (using Excel VBA) once but will not set the theme as the default. How do I set the theme as the new default?

```
Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application") 
PPApp.Visible=True                                                                                              
Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Add                   
PPPres.ApplyTemplate ("Location")
```

Much thanks to David for the ideas below but, unfortunately they do not work for my intended application. I am trying to create a macro that will set the default theme on open so that I can distribute that file to my org and control the slide template we are all working off of. This macro found [HERE](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.word.docmanagement/distributing-themes/104338) is very close but I cannot find syntax that will lock in the applied template. Thoughts?

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Dim ThemePath As String
    Dim ThemeFile As String
    Dim FullPath As String

    ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen16x9

    ThemeFile = "TestTemplate.potx"
    ThemePath = "File Path"
    FullPath = ThemePath + ThemeFile

    On Error Resume Next
        ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate (FullPath)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox (ThemeFile & " was not found in " & ThemePath)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "new default template"? As in: Every time you open PowerPoint a new Presentation file, will use a particular template?

Comment: Try this: http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/133460-set-change-powerpoint-default-template-(2007)

Comment: I should have been more precise. What I meant to say is "new default THEME".

Comment: Does the above suggestion not work? As I understand it, that should basically replicate the functionality of using a Normal.dot in MS Word, which is the template/theme applied to new Word Documents.  If you do what that post suggests, it should apply a particular template/theme to new PPT Presentations.  You can create the POTX file and set the desired Theme there.

Comment: I do not want to do anything on open. The macro will be implemented as a ribbon customization. David, I'm testing it now and will post back with the result. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "default" if you don't want to do anything on Open. Consider revising your question to explain in more detail what exactly are the desired results, and how your current code fails to accomplish that.

Comment: David, I've updated the post. Your link helps to bring in additional powerpoint themes, if the file location has them, but does not set a default theme. The link implies that the individual who implemented this had to run a macro to set the default. I'm looking for the syntax to set the default.

Comment: How do you intend to run the syntax, if not through a macro?  Of course you have to run a macro to set this default.  The macro can be called from the ribbon OnLoad event.

Comment: You're right David. I am using a macro. The issue for me is not when the macro gets loaded (I can figure that part out) but how to set the default theme in VBA.

Comment: Doesn't that link suggest creating a POTX file and saving it to a particular location? This would then be used by PPT when you create presentations.  If you do this, then, you should not need to "set" the default theme, as I understand it, because the Application will always use the blank.POTM file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years too late, but I don't think that this question was ever adequately answered. In your code above you should set the following string variables to:

```
ThemeFile = "blank.potx" '(it has to be "blank" or else it won't work)
ThemePath = "C:\Users\" vba.environ("username") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"
```

http://youpresent.co.uk/set-the-default-template-when-powerpoint-starts/